# JSF page values gets cleared when button pressed

Tags: java, jsf

I have a JSF page with scope defined as request.
In one of the action method of first button I am assigning values to page elements as

```
bean.setEmpNo("abc");
```

In another button I am calling a method to save values to database. When I click second button values which I assigned by clicking first button gets cleared.

Is this because my scope is request?
What are the best ways to keep the values assigned to page attributes even though I invoke other buttons in same page?

My JSF version is 1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes request scope's life is from request to response only.. if you want it for the same view you can use `ViewScope`

Comment: AFAIK there is no view scope in JSF 1.1. Thus it would have to be session scope.

Comment: Oops.. didn't notice the version. yes you can move to session scope then but you need to be more careful then

Comment: Yes session scope is somewhat too wide for many cases. An alternative might be JBoss Seam which addresses that problem for JSF 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be a scoping problem. If you click the first button, you have a new request and get a new/cleared instance of your bean. You'd have to make the bean session scoped (unless you're using JBoss Seam which supports finer grained scopes between request and session).

Comment: I have noticed that if I make my JSF page elements property as readonly ="false", then even when I click second button to save values, it retains the values. But if I make readonly = "true" that values gets null when I click the second button. Why is that so?